# SQL to Linq conversion - Max(), Groupby, Limit/page

Tags: linq

I've been stuck for the whole day trying to convert the following mariadb sql code to linq. Might anyone be able to help a newbie at linq?

```
select * from
(
select *, max(dateCreated) from CKDExtract a
inner join PatientExtract b
where a.PatientId = b.PatientExtractId
group by a.PatientID
) as t1
where t1.PatientGender like 'm'
LIMIT 0,100
```

Here is my current progress:

```
        var query = (
                            from p in fhtDB.Ckdextract
                            group p by p.PatientId into g
                            orderby g.Key
                            join pr in fhtDB.PatientExtract on g.Key
                            equals pr.PatientExtractId
                            into h
                            select new
                            {
                                allRemainingItems = g.OrderByDescending(t => t.DateCreated).First(),
                                patientData = h
                            }
                      ).Skip(startRow).Take(endRow - startRow).ToList();
        ;
```

However, this is not able to filter out the PatientGender.

Thank you,
Sean.

Comment: That is because you have not added a `Where()` clause in your LINQ.

Comment: I've tried the where clause at several places but the data does not come out correctly. Perhaps you can show me where you think it should be placed?

Comment: Between Select and Skip like `Where(g=>g.patientData.PatientGender =='m').Skip(startRow).Take...` . Here the condition needs to be the one you need.

Comment: Where (g=>g.patientData.First().PatientGender == "m"). Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have two tables: `PatientExtract` and `CkdExtract`. Every `PatientExtract` has zero or more `CkdExtracts`. Every `CkdExtract` belongs to exactly one `PatientExtract`. This standard one-to-many relation is implemented using a foreign key. Something similar to:

```
class PatientExtract
{
     public int PatientExtractId {get; set;}  // primary key

     public Gender Gender {get; set;}
     ... // other properties
}
class CkdExtract
{
     public int CkdExtractId {get; set;} // primary key

     // every CkdExtract belongs to exactly one PatientExtract using foreign key:
     public int PatientId {get; set;}

     ... // other properties
}
```

> Requirement: given as input a Gender value m, a skipValue, and a takeValue, give me (certain properties of) all PatientExtracts that have this gender, each with their CkdExtracts. Do this with the skip / take and order by increasing primary key value

If you use LINQ method syntax instead of query syntax, the query is simple:

```
Gender gender = Gender.M;
IQueryable<PatientExtract> patientExtracts = ...
IQueryable<CkdExtract> ckdExtracts = ...
var result = patientExtracts                                  // take all PatientExtracts
    .Where(patientExtract => patientExtract.Gender == gender) // keep only the M genders

    .GroupJoin(ckdExtracts,                             // GroupJoin with CkdExtracts
    patientExtract => patientExtract.PatientExtractId,  // from each PatientExtract take primary key
    ckdExtract => ckdExtract => PatientId,              // from each CkdExtract take foreign key
    (patientExtract, ckdExtracts) => new                // when they match, make one new object
    {
        // select only the properties you actual plan to use
        PatientExtractId = patientExtract.PatientExtractId,
        // no need, because you know the value: Gender = PatientExtract.Gender,
        ... // other Patient properties

        CkdExtracts = ckdExtracts
            .OrderBy(ckdExtract => ckdExtract.DateCreated)
            .Select(ckdExtract => new
            {
                // again: select only the CkdExtract properties you plant to use
                Id = ckdExtract.CkdExtractId,
                CreationDate = ckdExtract.DateCreated,
                ...

                // no need for the foreign key, you know the value!
                // PatientExtractId = ckdExtract.PatientId,
            },
    })

    // not sure whether it is needed to order by primary key; probably already ordered
    .OrderBy(patient => patient.Id)
    .Skip(skipValue)
    .Take(takeValue);
```